# Swift: Passing in functions that throw exceptions

Tags: swift, error-handling

I have the following toy example

```
func identity<T>(a : T) -> T{
  return a
}

func applyIdentity<T>(f : T->T, t:T) -> T{
  return f(t)
}

applyIdentity(identity, t:1)
```

And this works without a hitch. However, once I try to throw an exception in identity like so:

```
enum MyError: ErrorType{
  case MyErrorFoo
};

func identity<T>(a : T) throws -> T{
  if (true) {
    return a
  } else {
    throw MyError.MyErrorFoo
  }
}
...
```

The type checker complains on the `applyIdentity(identity, t:1)` call with message:

```
Argument for generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your (second) `identity()` method can throw an error, therefore it has the type
`T throws -> T`, not `T -> T`.

If `applyIdentity()` should just forward
an error thrown in `f()` to the caller then you can define it as

```
func applyIdentity<T>(f : T throws ->T , t:T) rethrows -> T {
    return try f(t)
}
```

See also ["Declarations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) in the Swift book:

> **Rethrowing Functions and Methods**
>
> A function or method can be declared with the `rethrows` keyword to
>   indicate that it throws an error only if one of it’s function
>   parameters throws an error. These functions and methods are known as
>   *rethrowing functions* and *rethrowing methods*. Rethrowing functions and
>   methods must have at least one throwing function parameter.